# PostgreSQL 9.6 query run more than 24 hours in nested loop

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that I run in my PostgreSQL 9.6 database and it runs for more than 24 hours and doesn't finish.

My select consist from few joins :

```
SELECT a.inst_prod_id,
       product_id,
       nap_area2,
       nap_phone_num,
       nap_product_id,
       b.nap_makat_cd,
       b.nap_discount_num,
       b.nap_debt_line,
       nap_act_start_dt,
       nap_act_end_dt,
       b.row_lastmant_dttm,
       b.row_added_dttm
FROM   ps_rf_inst_prod a,
       nap_ip_discount b
WHERE  nap_crm_status  = 'C_04'
AND    a.setid  || ''= 'SHARE'
AND    b.setid  || ''= 'SHARE'
AND    a.inst_prod_id = b.inst_prod_id
AND    b.nap_makat_cd IN (SELECT term_code
         FROM   tv_finterm
         WHERE  pricing_method_code in ('2', '4')
         AND    start_date <= b.nap_rishum_date
         AND    coalesce(end_date, to_date('01/01/2095','DD/MM/YYYY')) >=
                b.nap_rishum_date
         AND    coalesce(end_date, to_date('01/01/2095','DD/MM/YYYY')) !=
                start_date)
AND    b.nap_act_end_dt > clock_timestamp()
AND    TRUNC(b.nap_act_start_dt) < TRUNC(b.nap_act_end_dt)
AND (b.row_lastmant_dttm >  to_date('01/01/2005','DD/MM/YYYY') OR
      b.nap_rishum_date > to_date('01/01/2005','DD/MM/YYYY') OR
      b.row_added_dttm > to_date('01/01/2005','DD/MM/YYYY'))
AND   b.nap_discount_num IN (SELECT k.discount_line
         FROM   tv_discounts_details k
         WHERE  PERCENT IS NOT NULL
         AND    k.start_month = 1)
AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT /*+index(c TC_FINTERMS_I_SERVICE) */
                     1
                    FROM   tc_finterms c
                    WHERE  c.area = a.nap_area2
                    AND    c.phone = a.nap_phone_num
                    AND    c.term_code = b.nap_makat_cd
                    AND    deb_cred_line_no = b.nap_debt_line
                    AND (payment_end_date > clock_timestamp())
                    AND    term_type = '2')
OR  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
         FROM   ip_service_discounts
         WHERE  service_uid = (a.inst_prod_id)::integer
         AND    service_code = b.nap_makat_cd
         AND    discount_code = b.nap_discount_num
         AND (end_date IS NULL OR coalesce(discount_end_date, clock_timestamp() + interval '1 days') > clock_timestamp())))
          and  b.nap_purch_instprod  = ' ';
```

Before trying to work on performance I checked locks and nothing returned :

```
=# select a1.query as blocking_query, a2. query as waiting_query, 
        t.schemaname ||'.'||t.relname as locked_table from pg_stat_activity            
        a1 join pg_locks p1 on a1. pid = p1.pid and p1.granted join pg_locks 
        p2 on p1.relation = p2.relation and not p2.granted join 
        pg_stat_activity a2 on a2. pid = p2.pid join pg_stat_all_tables t on 
         p1.relation = t.relid;
        blocking_query | waiting_query | locked_table
        ----------------+---------------+--------------
     (0 rows)
```

I checked the explain plan of my query :

```
 Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.43..7565655389.26 rows=1 width=93)
   Join Filter: (b.nap_discount_num = (k.discount_line)::numeric)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..7565653159.07 rows=2 width=93)
         ->  Seq Scan on ps_rf_inst_prod a  (cost=0.00..4337158.91     rows=40452 width=41)
               Filter: (((nap_crm_status)::text = 'C_04'::text) AND     (((setid)::text || ''::text) = 'SHARE'::text))
         ->  Index Scan using ps_nap_ip_discount on nap_ip_discount b      (cost=0.43..186920.69 rows=1 width=60)
               Index Cond: ((inst_prod_id)::text = (a.inst_prod_id)::text)
               Filter: (((nap_purch_instprod)::text = ' '::text) AND     (nap_act_end_dt > clock_timestamp()) AND (((setid)::text || ''::text) = 'SHARE'::text) AND (trunc(nap_act_start_dt, 'DDD'::text) < trunc(nap_act_end_dt, 'DDD'::text)) AND ((row_lastmant_dttm > to_date('01/01/2005'::text, 'DD/MM/YYYY'::text)) OR (nap_rishum_date >     to_date('01/01/2005'::text, 'DD/MM/YYYY'::text)) OR (row_added_dttm > to_date('01/01/2005'::text, 'DD/MM/YYYY'::text))) AND ((NOT (SubPlan 2)) OR (NOT (SubPlan 3))) AND (SubPlan 1))
               SubPlan 2
                 ->  Index Scan using tc_finterms_ix1 on tc_finterms c (cost=0.56..8.60 rows=1 width=0)
                   Index Cond: (((area)::text = (a.nap_area2)::text) AND ((phone)::text = (a.nap_phone_num)::text))
                   Filter: (((term_type)::text = '2'::text) AND     (payment_end_date > clock_timestamp()) AND ((term_code)::numeric =     b.nap_makat_cd) AND (deb_cred_line_no = (b.nap_debt_line)::double     precision))
               SubPlan 3
                 ->  Index Scan using ip_service_discounts_pkey on     ip_service_discounts  (cost=0.56..10.78 rows=1 width=0)
                       Index Cond: (service_uid = a.inst_prod_id)::integer)
                       Filter: (((service_code)::numeric = b.nap_makat_cd)     AND ((discount_code)::numeric = b.nap_discount_num) AND ((end_date IS NULL) OR (COALESCE((discount_end_date)::timestamp with time zone,     (clock_timestamp() + '1 day'::interval)) > clock_timestamp())))
                  SubPlan 1
                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tv_finterm  (cost=2290.83..17301.61     rows=26907 width=4)
                       Recheck Cond: (((pricing_method_code)::text = ANY     ('{2,4}'::text[])) AND (start_date <= b.nap_rishum_date))
                       Filter: ((COALESCE(end_date,     (to_date('01/01/2095'::text, 'DD/MM/YYYY'::text))::timestamp without time zone) >= b.nap_rishum_date) AND (COALESCE(end_date, (to_date('01/01/2095'::text,     'DD/MM/YYYY'::text))::timestamp without time zone) <> start_date))
                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_test_mariel      (cost=0.00..2284.11 rows=81126 width=0)
                             Index Cond: (((pricing_method_code)::text = ANY     ('{2,4}'::text[])) AND (start_date <= b.nap_rishum_date))
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1407.38 rows=43933 width=4)
         ->  Seq Scan on tv_discounts_details k  (cost=0.00..1187.71 rows=43933 width=4)
               Filter: ((percent IS NOT NULL) AND (start_month = 1))
(25 rows)
```

I run `vacuum analyze database` before running the query. Some info about the tables :

```
ps_rf_inst_prod - 32G 
nap_ip_discount-1G 
tc_finterms - 6G
tv_finterm - 100M
TV_FINTERM -  1G
```

This query is part of an app that I migrated from Oracle to PostgreSQL. I don't want to change the query much, looking for a way to change the plan to make it faster. I have indexes on ps_rf_inst_prod, when I delete the pipelines in :

```
  AND    a.setid  || ''= 'SHARE'
  AND    b.setid  || ''= 'SHARE'
```

The plan is changing and it uses indexes on ps_rf_inst_prod but it costs more and the performance is worse.

Comment: Why does this have an Oracle tag?

Comment: `a.setid  || ''= 'SHARE'` makes no sense whatsoever. It's identical to `a.setid = 'SHARE'` but prevents usage of a possible index on that column.

Comment: If your queries take too long and there isn't a lock problem, that's a sign of poor structuring and missing indexes. Also that pointless concatenation `setid || ''`. Add more redundant fields where you need to, to simplify the queries, add some default values instead of coalescing if possible. That will help a lot. And put some btree indexes on the filters and maybe hash indexes on the join fields.